# When I make a Keyframe it won't show up in Dope Sheet or Timeline. (See Picture)

Tags: keyframes

I am trying to animate the strength of an emission node so it emits a lower amount of light to a higher amount of light, however, when I right click and click on "insert keyframe" nothing shows up in the timeline editor even though the strength is highlighted yellow. See image below

[image]

Comment: what you show is the Timeline, not the Dopesheet, to see the keyframe you need to have the node selected, is it?

Comment: @moonboots yes I just selected the node and the keyframe is now showing up in the dope sheet, thank you so much

Comment: could you please share your file, at least the object with the emission node? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/